# PICkit 2 VPP voltage level error. Check target & retry operation. Error in PICkit 2

Tags: pic, embedded, error, pickit

We are using PICkit 2 (STL035V2.0 [See here](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/silicon-technolabs-pickit2-pic-microcontroller-usb-programme-16658533397.html) )  to program a PIC 16F676. We got the error :

> PICkit 2 VPP voltage level error. Check target & retry operation.
>   Error in PICkit 2.
>
> We also get the error: Invalid OSCCAL Value detected warning.

We just found a solution and would like to post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the PICkit we are using is little different from standard PICkits. We placed the IC at the wrong position on the bed.Ours is a 14 pin IC (PIC 16F676). So It gave the errors

> PICkit 2 VPP voltage level error. Check target & retry operation.
>   Error in PICkit 2.

In this PIC kit [See here](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/silicon-technolabs-pickit2-pic-microcontroller-usb-programme-16658533397.html) it is quite different, and you can see that we have to place the IC in the 3rd position starting from the top.(For 14 pin IC, 8 Pin IC and 20 Pin IC) . And For the 18 Pin IC, you need to keep it where it is marked as 18.

[image: Refer this Image for Position]

So that will solve the first error.

And for the second error,

> Invalid OSCCAL Value detected warning.

Just select the following in PICKit Programmer Software:

1. Select Tools->Check Connection.
2. Goto Device Family Menu.
3. Select the correct device family. Ours was Midrange->Standard. (PIC 16F676)
4. If you are not able to select device manually, check the Programmer menu, and Check "Manual Device Select"
5. Check if the OSCALL value is not highlighted in Red color.

[image: Pickit 2 Software]

Now try reading, blank check, erase,etc.

**Note: This is for this version (STL035V2.0) Version only. Check Your Pickit for the placing the IC at the correct position.**

Comment: You found that placing the PIC16F676 in the fourth row works. What passes for documentation [image](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61q2Zf1ZVKL._SL1020_.jpg)  recommends the third row. There is a jumper to select between 24-40 pins DIPs and 8-14-18-20 DIPs. The STL035V2.0 seems a bit of a hazard for PIC device programming.

Comment: Good share [Dann](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/193751/dan1138), I'll check by placing the controller in that pin and let you know. Can you share the link of your finding?

Comment: @ReejeshPK - I don't know whether *Dan1138* found it in the same place as I did, but I found the image he kindly linked on this product's [Amazon India page here](https://www.amazon.in/Silicon-TechnoLabs-PICkit2-Microcontroller-Programmer/dp/B075RHTL5G). See the 5th image down on the left side. (P.S. *Dan* will have been notified of your comment, as his was the only comment when you replied - *but* unless you use the "`@`name" syntax, you may find some people will not get notified - the rules are quite complex. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019 for more info.)

Comment: @Reejesh PK ,@SamGibson, The link Sam posted is where I found the image. The web site for company that makes the programmer is printed on the board. You will find a lower quality image on that web page as well.

Comment: Thank You @Dan1138 and @ SamGibson. You guys are right. For the 8,14 and 20 PIn we should place it at the thrid row, I tested it by reading, writing and erasing with a PIC16f676 and it works fine with the third row and not with the fourth one. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @ReejeshPK You could mark this answer as "accepted" too